# Can't reach Node.js testing from Chrome on a usb tethered Android device

Tags: node.js

I can't reach Node.js testing from a usb tethered Android device (Chrome) using IPv4 address.

Node hello world running on Win7 PC works great locally using computer name,  IPv4 address, localhost, etc, etc. on ports 1337, 8080, etc.

No problems though reaching Apache in the same manner from Android (using IPv4 address)!

Is it a configuration issue?

Code :

```
var portNum = 8080;  //1337;
http.createServer(_handler).listen( portNum );
```

Comment: Are your Android device and your server on the same local network? Are you trying to reach the server with a local IP (192.168.1.x) or an Internet IP?

Comment: USB tether to my PC appears to create a LAN with mobile device from which Apache/port 80 is visible via local IP ( http://192.168.1.4/folder_name ).  Android chrome appears to add a trailing "/" to http address, which perhaps is automatically understood by Apache but not by Node (?)

Comment: BTW I'm not using Node Express. Chrome on PC does not add a trailing "/" slash to URLs the way Android Chrome does.  I've noticed that Apache config file (httpd.conf ) specifically discusses URL trailing slashes, so maybe Node also requires config settings to properly handle them (?)

Comment: Node doesn't throw any errors, and the request handler is never executed;  the Android chrome browser just shows "web page not available"....

Comment: Problem Solved ! Turned out to be a Window Firewall issue, which appears to block everything but port 80 which Apache was using.